# What operator is responsible for accessing/reading objects and arrays in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to count the number of reads and writes to memory in a given function, I am new to c++ and memory handling.
I know that for writes to memory I need to overload (edit) the New operator since I am only interested in counting objects and arrays only, but I still have no idea what is the process? operator responsible for reading from memory so I can look it up.

for example:
when I do
`A[1] = B[1] + C[1]`
that has 1 write and 2 reads from memory.

Comment: `operator[]` returns a *reference* to the object, which then has the usual read/write characteristics of any other variable.

Comment: Every time you use a variable it *might* read from memory.

Comment: Also `x = 1;` writes to memory. <- no `new` operator!

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overloading-subscript-or-array-index-operator-in-c/

Comment: the question depends entirely on what those `A`, `B`, and `C` are. were they custom classes, you could override `operator[]` to log/debug whatever (e.g. via a returned proxy / smart reference). but as written, it's too broad.

Comment: AB and C are arrays, I want to count reads and writes for objects (int, string etc.) and arrays only.

Comment: A better solution is to have the compiler print the assembly language for a function then count the memory read and write instructions.

Comment: @MarkRansom [No, it doesn't](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.sub).

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings that description looks like it only applies to arrays or pointers, not to a custom class implementation of `operator[]` like `std::vector` for instance.

Comment: @MarkRansom If we're talking about overloaded `operator[]`, then it can return whatever you like. In context, though, with the OP wishing to hook into object and array accesses at the lowest level, that seems unlikely. The built-in `operator[]` does not return a reference; that's a misconception.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings according to the link you gave me it returns a lvalue or xvalue.  But I don't see any practical difference between those and a reference, and the reference is more general.

Comment: @MarkRansom In C++, a "reference" means a `T&`. An expression using built-in `[]` is an lvalue or xvalue expression of type `T`. It's not a reference in C++ parlance. It's common to assume that it would be, because it's an expression "referring" to an existing object elsewhere, and because in order to achieve that in our own code we have to use references (`T&`). But that is not a constraint faced by the implementation, so the standard has no need to get references involved here. Consider that built-in `[]` exists in C, too, which has no reference types.

Comment: @MarkRansom Also, you can't "return a lvalue"; value categories pertain to expressions, not objects.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I didn't say they were the same thing, I said you couldn't tell the difference.

Comment: @MarkRansom Okay, you said earlier _"`operator[]` returns a reference to the object"_ which is factually inaccurate, so I was just correcting that. I guess we can move on now. Good evening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ does not have an operator that performs memory accesses.

Various C++ constructs may access memory, but compilers are given wide latitude to optimize code as it sees fit. It can load values from memory into registers and do a bunch of operations on those registers at the request of your code, then write the value out to memory. So even though in C++ it may *appear* to be doing many memory accesses, optimized code may only be doing a single read and a single write.

So trying to "count the number of reads and writes to memory in a given function" by looking at C++ code, or doing anything within the C++ language, is folly.

Comment: Is C different? is it possible in C language instead of c++

Comment: I was asked to use LLVM/Clang but that is also all new to me, I saw that it's used with the C family that is why I used C++ but other C languages are fine with me.

Comment: @DoaaRadwan C++ is an abstraction. You're not actually programming a computer, but _describing a program_. The compiler writes a computer program for you, with the same semantics as your description. This may sound academic or pedantic, but it's actually really important to remember if you want to properly understand C++ and things like exactly what Nicol described. To answer your question: C is _also_ an abstraction, though it is slightly closer to the metal in some ways for historical reasons. I do not believe that this is one of those ways in which it is different from C++.

Comment: @DoaaRadwan You could, however, ask your compiler for the _assembly_ of the computer program that it's created from your description ... and, reading it, analyse how many memory accesses that program will make from some given function.

Comment: I understand what C and other high level languages do, and have used assembly Language before but I am supposed to create something that should work with any function not a one time count for a specific function. I guess I will have to discuss it further with my mentor.

Comment: @Doaa: To be honest, then, it sounds like your mentor/teacher doesn't understand C and C++ in the way that I've described. At the very least, they're talking about a rather high-level notion of "reading from / writing to memory" that doesn't entirely correspond to _actual_ accesses at runtime. We can still reason about the high-level notions; every lvalue-to-rvalue conversion counts, for example. But you're stuck doing that by reading your code; there's no tool you can inject into your program to do it automatically, for reasons given above. (I bet you weren't supposed to automate it anyway.)

Comment: tl;dr: No, keep doing it the way you've been doing it so far.

Comment: to be fair to my mentor whats he said was to "Implement using LLVM/Clang, and the output of the instrumentation should return something like this for each method: "function test: reads = 20; writes = 10". I used C++ as it was the language associated with Clang.

Comment: @DoaaRadwan Okay, you didn't say that before. That sounds more involved than a simple counting game that you'd find in early University courses, which is how I'd interpreted your question. We'd probably have to know the context of your course and instruction in order to divine what your instructor wants. Probably a good idea, indeed, to have a conversation with them. Good luck!